# How to look for the parent of an object - Eslint selectors with espree

Tags: javascript, eslint

Currently I'm working on some code to disallow the use of global constants in a user input area that allows them to use formulas.

I'm using espree as a parser.

Currently I have some working code to find the use of an global or the immediate child of a global but if I set something like Parent.Child0.Child1 the rule stops working.

I guess it would be easier to find that given any number of childs if the parent is in the blacklist we should ban the sentence but I don't know how to access it.

It may be quite simple but I did not find anything regarding this topic, I took a look on this page for reference but it did not have the answer: https://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/selectors

```
const allowedReadOnlyGlobals = ['object1', 'object3', 'object3'];
allowedReadOnlyGlobals.forEach(globalObj =>
    disallowedSelectors.push({
        selector: `AssignmentExpression[left.object.name="${globalObj}"]`,
        message: `It is not allowed to replace members of the '${globalObj}' object.`
    })
);
```

I expect some rule like this one, but I'm not sure if that will exist

```
selector: `AssignmentExpression[object.parent="${globalObj}"]`,
```

(The rest of the code I expect it to be the same)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research the selector query was the following:

```
selector: `AssignmentExpression[left] MemberExpression[object.name="${globalObj}"]`,
```

I expect this helps someone in the future.